# Unwind segue to a view controller which has not been presented yet?

Tags: ios, iphone, navigation, segue

I have an app with a login controller. In the app I have a settings controller, in which the user can disable the login controller, so he can automatically login.

This all works fine, except for one situation:

The user disables the login controller and terminate the app, later he starts the app again, and because the login controller is disabled (which is checked in the app delegate), the app starts without presenting the login controller (and therefore not executing any code of the login controller). 
Then he goes to the settings view controller and enables the login again.
Now, when he tries to logout, the unwind segue is not performed.

Is it possible, that the view controller, which is the target of the unwind segue, must have been presented at least 1 time, other wise the unwind segue is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. An unwind segue is the only kind of segue that doesn't instantiate a view controller, so the controller you're going to must have been previously instantiated. Not only that, but it must still be present in the hierarchy of controllers.